# Calculate inactive time jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to get total inactive second in the site.

For example.

If user do not done anything in the site so counter is started to 1.

if user interrupt in that tab counter is set to 0

if user again inactive counter is started.

if user go to another tab on 10 second so timer is stop to 10 second and when he get back to that tab it's start again to 10 second.

```
idleTime = 0;

//Increment the idle time counter every second.
var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 1000);

function timerIncrement()
{
    idleTime++;
    console.log(idleTime);

}

//Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
$(document).bind('mouseover click keydown scroll', function () {
    idleTime = 0;
});
```

Thank in advance.

Comment: Please show effort and code as per the [help].We need a [mcve]

Comment: I have edit the comment. Sorry about that

Comment: can you add what is expected and actual output? What does not work in your code?

Comment: When I am go to another tab timer is not stop. It should stop when we go to another tab and again start when we come back to that tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Tracking Inactive User
idleTime_inactive = 0;
var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrements, 1000);
var idleTime_inactivetemp = false;
function timerIncrements()
{
    console.log(idleTime_inactive);
    if(idleTime_inactivetemp == false) {
        idleTime_inactive++;
    }
}
function get_pagescroll_per(){
    var wintop = $(window).scrollTop(), docheight = $(document).height(), winheight = $(window).height();
    var  scrolltrigger = 0.95;
    return (wintop/(docheight-winheight))*100;
}

$(document).bind('mouseover click keydown scroll', function () {
    idleTime_inactive = 0;
});

document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
  if(document.hidden == true) {
    idleTime_inactivetemp = true;
  } else {
    idleTime_inactivetemp = false;
  }
}, false);
```

Comment: Why `document.addEventListener("visibilitychange"` and not `document.on("visibilitychange"` ?